# How to Split the Text Gzipped files for Spark processing

Tags: apache-spark

We receive 10 GB text gzipped files from upstream. While reading the file using spark dataframe found only 1 vcore is getting used for 1 file.

Is it possible to split the files into multiple files and then use Spark Dataframe, so multiple vcores can improve the read performance for gzipped file?
Is it possible using zcat and csplit to create multiple files, is there a chance of Data loss or any other known issue?

Answer (score 1):

Gzipped files can't be partitioned. If you need partitioned in the zipped file, you need to use snappy format.

Or you need to partition the file explicitly using repartition.

```
spark.read.json("....gz").repartition(N) // N = number of partition you want.
```

Comment: repartition will still use 1 vcore to read. I was looking more into like uncompressing from gzip to text and then split and create multiple file, but I couldn't make it work.